# SQL Display Table as Output using Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I need to get a table name as output, following is a sample code.

`eg.     set @table = [dbo].[mytable]`

```
     Insert into <table 1> ( a, b, c, d as table name, i )
     select a, b , c, '+@table+' , i from <table 2>
     inner join <table2> on  a = tmp.a `
```

In the insert statement, i need column D to have a table name applied to all the records. I'm getting an error "multipart cannot be bound" is there a specific way to call the table name for display only purpose?

Thanks!

Comment: Your sample query makes no sense at all.  What is `tmp`?  Why a self join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you're inserting text, so put it in quotes

```
set @table = '[dbo].[mytable]'
```

Second, alias your tables and apply to the columns (you had table2 for both)

```
 Insert into [Table1] ( a, b, c, d, i )
 select t1.a, t1.b , t1.c, @table , t1.i 
 from [Table2] t1
 inner join [Table2] t2 on  t1.a = t2.a
```